# SOL transfer via CPI signed with PDA throws fails

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js, anchor-lang, systemprogram

I am trying to make a SOL transfer from the **bank** account into the **client** account, but the operation fails with the following error:
`Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account` which is strange because all involved accounts are writable and a program derived address (PDA) should be able to sign the instruction (If I understood [the docs](https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_in_depth/PDAs.html) correctly).

This is my code:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct ClaimPayment<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub client: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub bank: Account<'info, Bank>,
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [client.key().as_ref(), bank.key().as_ref()],
        bump = client_pda.bump
    )]
    pub client_pda: Account<'info, ClientPDA>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

pub fn claim_payment(ctx: Context<ClaimPayment>, payment: u64) -> Result<()> {
    let seeds = &[
        ctx.accounts.client.to_account_info().key.as_ref(),
        ctx.accounts.bank.to_account_info().key.as_ref(),
        &[ctx.accounts.client_pda.bump],
    ];
    let signer_seeds = &[&seeds[..]];
    let transfer_cpi_context = CpiContext::new(
        ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
        system_program::Transfer {
            from: ctx.accounts.bank.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.client.to_account_info(),
        },
    )
    .with_signer(signer_seeds);
    system_program::transfer(transfer_cpi_context, payment)?;
    let client_pda = &mut ctx.accounts.client_pda;
    client_pda.paid = true;
    let bank = &mut ctx.accounts.bank;
    bank.payments += 1;
    Ok(())
}
```

And the Javascript for testing the method:

```
let [clientPda, bump] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress([provider.publicKey.toBuffer(), BANK_KEYPAIR.publicKey.toBuffer()], program.programId);
await program.methods
  .claimPayment(1_000_000_000)
  .accounts({
    client: provider.publicKey,
    bank: BANK_KEYPAIR.publicKey,
    clientPda: clientPda,
  })
  .rpc();
```

Somebody knows which could be the problem? Would it make any difference if I use a PDA for `bank` instead of a regular account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a system program transfer instruction, the funding account (the one sending the SOL) must sign the instruction,  in your case it needs to be signed by the `bank` account. But since it's not a PDA this can't be done inside the program.

You are using the `client_pda` to sign the transfer instead of using the `bank` account which is why you see this `Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account`.

You can use the code suggested in [Solana Cookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/references/programs.html#how-to-transfer-sol-in-a-program) to **transfer lamports from your program owned accounts to any account at all**:

```
/// Transfers lamports from one account (must be program owned)
/// to another account. The recipient can by any account
fn transfer_service_fee_lamports(
    from_account: &AccountInfo,
    to_account: &AccountInfo,
    amount_of_lamports: u64,
) -> ProgramResult {
    // Does the from account have enough lamports to transfer?
    if **from_account.try_borrow_lamports()? < amount_of_lamports {
        return Err(CustomError::InsufficientFundsForTransaction.into());
    }
    // Debit from_account and credit to_account
    **from_account.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= amount_of_lamports;
    **to_account.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += amount_of_lamports;
    Ok(())
}

/// Primary function handler associated with instruction sent
/// to your program
fn instruction_handler(accounts: &[AccountInfo]) -> ProgramResult {
    // Get the 'from' and 'to' accounts
    let account_info_iter = &mut accounts.iter();
    let from_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
    let to_service_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;

    // Extract a service 'fee' of 5 lamports for performing this instruction
    transfer_service_fee_lamports(from_account, to_service_account, 5u64)?;

    // Perform the primary instruction
    // ... etc.

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Can I still use instruction to transfer SOL? Using CPI will show clearly show sol transfer as an instruction in explorer/solscan.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're deriving seeds to sign this transaction on behalf of `client_pda`, but the transfer is from `bank` to `client`. Your `bank` will need to sign for this transfer, not `client_pda`.

Comment: I thought normal accounts like bank cannot be used to sign CPI calls, even if the account is owned by the Program. Do you know how could I perform a CPI sign using the bank account? Or should I rather look into doing all this using PDAs instead? I mean replacing bank account by a bankPDA so I can transfer funds via CPI.

Comment: This is correct–I assumed `bank` was your PDA. In this case, yeah, you should do what Ander said: make `bank` a PDA owned by your program.